# SDL Init slows the program while code is correct and has run perfectly before

Tags: c, runtime-error, sdl-2

I have a SDL2 program that works perfectly. But from time to time, when I compile, execute and close several times my program, it slows drastically when calling SDL_Init(). I can still see my console, but it is just very slow and needs 5 minutes to resume.

It happens when I use "SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING" as a flag. But after 5 minutes, it runs the program smoothly.
But when I use "SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS" as a flag, the program freezes when calling SDL_PollEvent() instead of SDL_Init().

I use a development lib of SDL_2.0.9 dynamically included. I repeat that this program has already been running perfectly and breaks itself while no mod is applied to the code.

Actually, the code is working. I don't think it is the problem here.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    srand(_getpid());


    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
        printf("ERR SDL_INIT\n");
        SDL_Quit();

        system("PAUSE");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //* Basically the rest of my program.

}
```

When running the program step by step, the program clearly slows when calling SDL_Init().

Here are some pics of the problem :

[image: My program starts normally]

[image: And then enters SDL_Init() without return errors or anything and slows down]

It should actually initialize SDL fast, as it does most of the time, and then continue executing the program without blocking calling SDL_PollEvent().

I can more or less solve the problem by rebooting my pc but it occurs quite sometimes.

Tell me if other information I didn't think of is needed.

EDIT :

As suggested, I tried writing a minimal verifiable code to confirm the problem doesn't come from the code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    printf("ERR SDL_INIT\n");
    SDL_Quit();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

SDL_Window* window = NULL;
window = SDL_CreateWindow("WindowName", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

if (!window) {  //test si la fenetre existe bien
    printf("ERR SDL_WINDOW\n");
    SDL_Quit();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);


SDL_bool quit = SDL_FALSE;
SDL_Event e;

while (!quit) {

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 255, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {

        if (e.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE)
            quit = SDL_TRUE;

        switch (e.type) {

        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                quit = SDL_TRUE;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);


}

SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And now, as SDL_Init() is called using SDL_INIT_VIDEO, the program freezes at the call of SDL_PollEvent(). The VS console returns me those lines at the exact moment of the freeze :

```
'MinimalVerifiableExample.exe' (Win32) : Chargé 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\hid.dll'. Impossible de trouver ou d'ouvrir le fichier PDB.
'MinimalVerifiableExample.exe' (Win32) : Chargé 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Impossible de trouver ou d'ouvrir le fichier PDB.
```

I don't know if it is related tho.

Comment: you could try oring the specific flags until it works: `SDL_INIT_TIMER |
SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK | SDL_INIT_HAPTIC | SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER | SDL_INIT_EVENTS`: this is the same as "everything". Now remove flags one-by-one if you feel they are not needed and see if it helps. Some not useful flags for you may cause trouble. Do you need force feedback? no? remove it, and so on

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I already tried using SDL_INIT_VIDEO or both SDL_INIT_VIDEO and SDL_INIT_EVENTS. But it didn't work. I don't use the other modules. when doing that, it slows on the SDL_PollEvent() func

Comment: there may be another unrelated issue in the rest of your program. Simplify it until it works 100% of the time, and if it still fails while very simple, you have your [mcve] that you can post here.

Comment: I heard in SDL 2.0.9 they rewrote a lot of joystick/controller stuff, which reportedly causes major lag on some systems. Try SDL 2.0.8.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you, that was the lib version that was the problem. I returned to 2.0.8 and it fixed it.